# Implementation of Google Sign up in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, google-authentication

I want to implement Google Sign up in my web application using libraries  suggested by Google like oauthclient.
I want my user to authenticate via google and get signed in.
Here is my views.py:

```
FLOW = flow_from_clientsecrets(
    settings.GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRETS_JSON,
    scope='profile email',#enter your required scope
    redirect_uri='http://127.0.0.1:8000/home',
    prompt='consent')

def gmail_authenticate(request):
    storage = DjangoORMStorage(CredentialsModel, 'id', request.user, 'credential')
    credential = storage.get() #credential of the user
    if credential is None or credential.invalid:
        #credential is not present or invalid
        #so, generating credential
        FLOW.params['state'] = xsrfutil.generate_token(settings.SECRET_KEY,
                                                       request.user)
        authorize_url = FLOW.step1_get_authorize_url()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(authorize_url)
    else:
        #if credential is present and valid
        http = httplib2.Http()
        http = credential.authorize(http)
        service = build('gmail', 'v2', http=http)
        print('access_token = ', credential.access_token)
        status = True
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'status': status})

def auth_return(request):
    get_state = bytes(request.GET.get('state'), 'utf8')
    if not xsrfutil.validate_token(settings.SECRET_KEY, get_state,
                                   request.user):
        return HttpResponseBadRequest()
    #storing credential to DB
    credential = FLOW.step2_exchange(request.GET.get('code'))
    storage = DjangoORMStorage(CredentialsModel, 'id', request.user, 'credential')
    storage.put(credential)
    print("access_token: %s" % credential.access_token)
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
```

The DjangoORMStorage class needs user instance but I don't want to create User until the user the verified my google. Help me to change my code and the Flow.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. SO isn't a free service code so please provide us your attemps and read [mcve]

Comment: sorry,I have now added my attempt 
Help me

Answer (score 2):

Just a simple google search returned plenty of relevant results:

1. [How to Add Social Login to Django](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/24/how-to-add-social-login-to-django.html)
2. [How to add Google and Github OAuth in Django](https://fosstack.com/how-to-add-google-authentication-in-django/)
3. [OAuth Authentication in Django with social-auth](https://medium.com/trabe/oauth-authentication-in-django-with-social-auth-c67a002479c1)
4. [Adding Social Authentication to Django](https://realpython.com/adding-social-authentication-to-django/)

Basically, add Python Social Auth library to your project and configure it to support Google.

Comment: Don't want to use social-django Or all-auth

Comment: As @Sfili_81 said, this isn't a free code service. No one is going to code it for you unless you do it yourself first and ask here if you get stuck somewhere. Also, be informative in your questions.

Comment: Sorry,
I have added my attempt